# TeX capacity exceeded error with polyglossia

Tags: xetex, overleaf, polyglossia, right-to-left, bidi

I'm using Overleaf in XeLaTeX to work with various different Semitic languages, and I'm trying to typeset their scripts. I've been using ArabTex and cJHebrew for Arabic and Hebrew respectively, but I'm trying to make the switch over to polyglossia. Polyglossia works successfully for Amharic, but when I try to compile with Arabic, Hebrew, Syriac or any other script written right-to-left as either the main or "other" languages, the document fails to compile and give this error

> File: gloss-arabic.ldf polyglossia: module for arabic
> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/bidi.sty
> Package: bidi 2022/07/18 v39.3 Bidirectional typesetting in plain TeX and LaTeX
> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=20000].
> \gb@ifnextchar #1#2#3->
> \let \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}\def \reserv...
> l.45 ...****************************************^^
> J%
> If you really absolutely need more capacity,
> you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

I'm not sure exactly what the issue is, but it clearly has something to do with the bidi package and switching from left-to-right to right-to-left writing, since it works with Amharic. I've included the code from the preamble below. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{coptic}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}




\newfontfamily{\syriacfont}[Script=Syriac]{Jerusalem.ttf}
\newfontfamily{\amharicfont}[Script=Amharic]{AbyssinicaSIL-Regular.ttf}


\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}} % optional; useful if paragraphs are to be numbered

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{6}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}


\newcommand{\RA}{$\rightarrow$}
\newcommand{\x}{\tipaLoweraccent[+.1ex]{\u{}}{h}}
\newcommand{\I}{\tipaUpperaccent[0.1ex]{\textsubrhalfring{}}{\i}}
\newcommand{\A}{\tipaUpperaccent[0.1ex]{\textsublhalfring{}}{\phantom{a}}}
\newcommand{\E}{\d{h}}
\newcommand{\til}{{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\sim$}}}
\newcommand{\e}{\textschwa}
\newcommand{\W}{\textsuperscript{w}}
\newcommand{\hamza}{\tipaLoweraccent[-0.6ex]{\textsubrhalfring{}}{\tipaUpperaccent[-0.2ex]{\textsubrhalfring{}}{\phantom{a}}}}
\newcommand{\?}{\tipaUpperaccent[0.1ex]{\textsubrhalfring{}}{\phantom{a}}}
\newcommand{\T}{\d{t}}
\newcommand{\p}{\pause}
\newcommand{\sh}{\v{s}}
\newcommand{\ts}{\d{s}}
\newcommand{\D}{\d{d}}


\setmainlanguage{english}

\setotherlanguages{amharic, arabic}
```

Comment: well you could make a bit of an effort to pin down the problem by removing more lines in your preamble. Add `\noautomath` after gb4e. And don't load packages like arabtex and coptic and cjhebrew with xelatex. They are not meant for this engine.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! As it turns out, the \noautomath command was the key. I'm fairly new to using XeLaTex, and I don't think that would have ever occurred to me. Thanks for the help. It seems to be working now.